selection not getting cleared after button click
I am wondering why the selection is not getting cleared or basically switching to -No Selection- option when Clear Selection button is clicked.


$("#clearTag").select2();

document.getElementById('clear-selection').addEventListener('click', function () {
console.log("button clicked");
$("#clearTag").val('');
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!-- Select2 CSS --><!-- Select2 JS --> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div>
<select id="clearTag" name="clearTag" >
  <option value="" >-No Selection-</option>
     
      <option value="Duplicate" >Duplicate</option>
      <option value="HandwrittenNote" >HandwrittenNote</option>
      <option value="Inappropriate" >Inappropriate</option>
      <option value="Incomplete" >Incomplete</option>
      <option value="Incorrect" >Incorrect</option>
    
      <option value="NameDiscrepancy" >NameDiscrepancy</option>
      <option value="Payment" >Payment</option>
</select>

</div>

<input type="button" id="clear-selection" value="Clear Selection!">



Is using $("#clearTag").val(''); not a correct way to go about it?

You need to trigger the change event on the select.


$("#clearTag").select2();

document.getElementById('clear-selection').addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log("button clicked");
    $("#clearTag").val('').trigger('change');;
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!-- Select2 CSS --><!-- Select2 JS --> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div>
<select id="clearTag" name="clearTag" >
  <option value="" >-No Selection-</option>
     
      <option value="Duplicate" >Duplicate</option>
      <option value="HandwrittenNote" >HandwrittenNote</option>
      <option value="Inappropriate" >Inappropriate</option>
      <option value="Incomplete" >Incomplete</option>
      <option value="Incorrect" >Incorrect</option>
    
      <option value="NameDiscrepancy" >NameDiscrepancy</option>
      <option value="Payment" >Payment</option>
</select>

</div>

<input type="button" id="clear-selection" value="Clear Selection!">



